# How to convert xml stored as clob to temporary table in DB2

Tags: xml, stored-procedures, db2, clob

The xml is stored in CLOB format in a table in DB2

I want to convert this xml into a  tabular format inside a stored procedure

Ex. xml is like this

```
 <Orders>
     <order id="1" name="order1" dateOfIssue="2015-01-09"/>
     <order id="2" name="order2" dateOfIssue="2009-01-08"/>
</Orders>
```

it should be inserted in table like This

```
id  | Name   | DateOFIssue
1   | order1 | 2015-01-09
2   | order2 | 2009-01-08
```

Comment: Sadly, you didn't mention your DB2 version and platform; consider using `XMLPARSE()` and `XMLTABLE()` if they are supported by your DB2 instance.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a Stored Procedure as described in your question, but the shortest path is to write a query using [`XMLTABLE`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0022195.html). This will look like here (untested):

```
select x.*
from yourTableWithCLOB, XMLTABLE('$CLOBCOLUMNNAME/Orders/order' columns
id int path '@id',
name varchar(20) path '@name',
DateOfIssue date path '@dateOfIssue'
) as x
```

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be going for the DB2 PureXML feature where XML data can be stored directly to the tables in the hierarchical form. And it can be retrieved through the XQuery and SQL which you can make it as a stored procedure.